# How to conditionally make http request in ngrx effect

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an effect that I would like to make a data call conditionally based on some value in the store.  Something like this:

```
  @Effect()
  loadRequestEffect$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<actions.RegisterDataSubscription>,
    withLatestFrom(
      this.store.select(dataManagementFeature)
    ),
    switchMap(([action, data]) => {
      if (...condition...) {
        return this.http
          .get()
          .pipe(
            map(data => new actions.SetEndpointData()),
          );
      }
      else {
        return of(new actions.SetEndpointLoading());
      }
    })
```

I thought I could just 'of' the new action within switchMap, but apparently not.  It won't compile with this complaint:

```
ERROR in src/app/store/data-management-store/effects.ts(22,15): error TS2345: Argument of type '([action, data]: [RegisterDataSubscription, State]) => Observable<SetEndpointData> | Observable<SetEndpointLoading>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: [RegisterDataSubscription, State], index: number) => ObservableInput<SetEndpointData>'.
  Type 'Observable<SetEndpointData> | Observable<SetEndpointLoading>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<SetEndpointData>'.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say *apparently not*, what is not happening that you expect to happen? And what is happening instead?

Comment: Updated question with compile error.

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle? It would be helpful.

Comment: fyi, i solved my issued by splitting the conditional into multiple actions.  thanks for looking.